# Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions, flutter-plugin

When I added **[permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)** plugin in flutter.
This Error Occured:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.   
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I tried to change the version of **plugin** and I also tried to run **flutter clean** but not worked.

If you know the answer of this question.Please answer this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

changing the compileSdkVersion to 30 or 31 in android\app\build.gradle can fix this issue

Comment: Thanks for this information. It solved my issue

Comment: Thanks! I had 30 but had to change to 31.

Comment: This must be a red herring though .. it's a cache issue so just updating your SDK isn't really solving the underline issue

Comment: this did not work for me. I get the same error with 31

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is a chance that you are using an outdated dependency. Removing it can solve it. However, I was facing the same issue and changing "compileSdkVersion" to 31 in build.gradle solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the compileSdkVersion to 31 and then it asked for 32. Now I am getting the following:

```
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Make sure that you fully go through the V2 migration. Keep in mind that some plugins might not be null safety or V2 compliant and that might be the issue. So you might want to remove those or find a way to replace them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is with Android Studio. I use a Mac with M1 processor and everytime there is an update with the Android studio, I need to do the following.

Go to Applications folder in Finder, right click on Android Studio -> Show Package contents.
Navigate inside the folder and create a new directory named jre and copy the contents of jbr into newly created jre. Restart Android studio and it worked fine for me.